# How can I use the /home directory on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, directory-structure

I've got a Mac that I can run either the Leopard (10.5) or Snow Leopard (10.6) version of OS X on. I'm using it to do web development/testing before publishing files to my production host.

On the production host my site's doc root is under the home directory (e.g. /home/stimulatingpixels/public_html) and I'd like to duplicate that location on the Mac. Unfortunately, their is a hidden and lock placeholder on the Mac that looks like a mounted drive with nothing in it sitting in the /home location.

I know from experience that it's unwise to move this and drop in your own /home directory because upgrades can cause it to be erased (and it doesn't get stored in the TimeMachine backup, by the way).

So, the question, is there anyway to safely use /home on a Mac either Leopard or Snow Leopard?

(Note: I realize this is very Mac specific and will be asking it in an Apple forum as well. Just wanted to ask here in addition to cover all the bases.)

Update: To help describe why I want to do this, in addition to the front end web site, I've got a series of scripts that I'd like to run as well. One of the main goals with being able to use the /home directory (and more specifically the same path from the servers root) is so that can use the same output paths on the development mac as well be used on the production server. I know there are ways to work around this, but I'd rather not have to deal with it. The real goal is to have all the files on the development Mac have the same filepath from the / root of the directory tree as the production server.

Another Update: The other reason that I forgot to mention earlier for this is setting up .htaccess paths when using basic authentication. Since those paths are from the file system root instead of the website docroot, they end up going through "/home" when that's part of the tree.

Comment: Sounds like you're using Wordpress or another CMS that doesn't handle local dev super-nicely.

Comment: I've added an update above. It's really more about secondary scripts that I run and wanting them to have the same filepath on the dev Mac as the production server.

Comment: Note: This might be so Mac specific that it's better to ask on the apple support site. To cover all the bases, I'm asking effectively the same thing here: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2138336&stqc=true

Comment: Your link to apple support forums is no longer active

Answer (score 63, accepted):

*NOTE: As of 2015, I no longer use or recommend this method. Instead I use [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com) to setup virtual machines for dev and testing. It's free, relatively easy, and allows better matching of the production environment. It completely separates the development environment and you can make as many as you need. **Highly recommended**. I'm leaving the original answer below for posterity's sake.*

---

I found an answer [here on the Apple forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2073807?tstart=0).

In order to reclaim the `/home` directory, edit the `/etc/auto_master` file and comment out (or remove) the line with `/home` in it. You'll need to reboot after this for the change to take effect (or, per nilbus' comment, try running `sudo automount -vc`). This works with Mac OS X 10.5 (Leopard). Your millage may vary for different versions, but it should be similar.

As noted on that forum post, you should also be aware that **Time Machine automatically excludes the `/home` directory and *does not* back it up**.

---

One note of warning, make sure to back up your `/home` directory manually before doing a system update. I believe one of the updates I did (from 10.6 to 10.7 for example) wiped out what I has stored in `/home` without warning. I'm not 100% sure that's what happened, but it's something to be on the lookout for.

Comment: No need to reboot; just run: sudo automount -vc

Comment: Apple changed the format of the URLs for their forum. I've updated the link to point to the new location.

Comment: and has since disappeared again, also not available on he web archive, another strong point for SO/SE!

Answer (score 12):

Putting it all together from the tips and hints above:

- edit  `/etc/auto_master` # *comment out the line with `/home` in it.*
- remount:

  `sudo automount -vc`
- make a softlink to the mac-ified dir:

  `sudo ln -s $HOME  /home/$USER`

At that point, your paths should match-up to your production paths. `env` vars will still point to `/Users/xxxx`, but anything you hard-code in a path in your `.bashrc` --or say, in `~/.pip/pip.conf`-- should be essentially equivalent. Worked for me.

re: ***"The real goal is to have all the files on the development Mac have the same filepath from the / root of the directory tree as the production server."***

On production, my deploy work might happen in `/opt/projects/projname`, so I'll just make sure my account can write into `/opt/projects` and go from there. I'd start by doing something like this:

`sudo mkdir /opt/projects
 sudo chown $USER /opt/projects
 mkdir /opt/projects/projname
 cd /opt/projects/projname`

With LVM, I'll set a separate partition for `/opt/`, and write app data there instead of `$HOME`. Then, I can grow the `/opt` file system in cases where I need more disk space for a project (LVM is your friend.)

Answer (score 12):

I tried it on Yosemite (OS X 10.10.1) the `sudo automount -vc` didn't work, I had to use `sudo umount /home`.

Therefore my workflow would be:

`# comment out line starting with /home
sudo vi "+g/^\/home/s/\//#\//" "+x" /etc/auto_master
sudo umount /home`

`# link actual home directory (/Users/<user>) to new 'home' (/home/<user>)
ln -s $HOME /home/$USER`

Answer (score 2):

I adapted the previous solutions to Big Sur (macOS 11.2), which is a bit more complicated due to the APFS file system changes. I managed to change `/home` by following these steps:

1. As recommended by Alan W. Smith, comment out the `/home` entry in `/etc/auto_master`.
2. As suggested by Marco Torchiano, run

   ```sh
   sudo umount /home
   ```
3. Since `/home` is currently a read-only link to `/System/Volumes/Data/home`, you have to change the latter. I did it with the following commands:

   ```sh
   cd /System/Volumes/Data/
   sudo rmdir home
   sudo ln -s <some other directory> home
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just run MAMP and use the Sites directory? You can develop off localhost and just have a bunch of aliases for your sites.  I'm not sure why you specifically need to use the home directory.

---

EDIT:
Ok, I think you are going about solving your problem the wrong way.

If it's HTML paths you are worried about, the begin everything with a slash "/" which will default it to the home dierectory.

If it's the references in your PHP, then you need to create a global (or similar) and set it as the root of your site.  Then you can reference everything from the global and when you move the site from dev to production all you need to change is the global.

Trying in a round-about way to develop from /home because it looks more like the production server is a bad idea.

Install MAMP, create the global somewhere high in the hierarchy and start re-referencing.  It'll be less pain in the long run.

Comment: The web server isn't the issue. I'm fine with running apache. What I'm really after is using the /home directory itself. The same questions would apply regardless of the server being used. I'll add a comment above, but the real reason is that I have some local script that I run and I'd like to be able to define the paths on my local dev box so they matches the ones on production. That way, I don't have to deal with changing them during deployment.

Comment: Just use a symbolic link and let your local script think it's operating on the /home directory.

Comment: But this is what using an environment like MAMP is for... So you can set up your dev environment however you like and the paths should be exactly the same.  Are you using relative or exact paths?

Comment: Matt: Symbolic links won't work in this directory. For example, right now, I've got the docroot set to "/www/stimulatingpixels/", but if I do: "sudo ln -s /www/stimulatingpixels/ /home/stimulatingpixels" the response is: "ln: /home/stimulatingpixels: Operation not supported"

Evernoob: I'm using exact paths, and that's really what I'm trying to work for. It's much less about the websever itself, but the ability to create a file at a location under the /home dir on the Mac that is the same as it will be on the production server. (Largely this is for other scripts outside the site itself.)

Comment: Evernoob: It's really the Perl scripts that support the site that I'm focused on. As you mention, PHP stuff is not an issue. I use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to get to the website's docroot when necessary. What I'd like to be able to do is have supporting perl scripts (for example, one that hits an external site and creates an include file at a specific path) setup so the output paths are the same on dev and prod. I know there are ways to work around this, but I'm interested in seeing if there is a way that I don't have to. That way, I keep my dev and prod environments as similar as possible.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question asked (and the question really belongs on another Stack Exchange site).